# Merging tables with similar structure and data

Tags: php, mysql, select, union

I'm working on a site that displays fantasy football stats. Every week of each season has its own table in the database (2014_week_1, 2014_week_2, etc). Every table has a row for each player with nearly 100 columns holding various information like the player's name, team, position, and stats they acquired that week.

For most of the website, I only needed to display a weekly breakdown of the players and the HTML table columns would look like this:

Name | Team | Position | Stat 1 | Stat 2 | Stat 3 | Stat 4 (so on and so forth)

This is achieved with a simple select. But now I need a way to display every week's data from a season in a table for a specific stat and position. The HTML table columns would look like this:

Name | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 | Week 5 | Week 6 (so on and so forth)

I tried using UNION, but it's not working exactly as I'd like. I need a way to determine exactly which week the data is being pulled from. Currently, I've got a table with a row for every player of every week, displaying their stat for that week, but there's only one column and the results are repeated. So, each week that a player plays it displays a row with that week's stat instead of one row for each player and a column for each week.

I've seen similar topics here and elsewhere, but none of them really accomplished what I needed and I can't find enough information about my problem to troubleshoot it without advice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if any additional information is required on my part, I'll be more than happy to oblige.

Comment: "But now I need a way to display every week's data from a season in a table for a specific stat and position. The HTML table columns would look like this:

Name | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 | Week 5 | Week 6 (so on and so forth)"

But what exact fields would be displayed in each "Week x" column? You did not describe that and it's important to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Sounds like merging all these silly `(2014_week_1, 2014_week_2, etc)` tables into a single table would be a better idea.

Comment: @ajmedway Like I said, it will display a specific stat. So, I need to combine the data from all the tables with the same year for each player and it will display a specific column's (stat) data for each week.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mean, if that's what I have to do then I will, but it will require quite a lot of recoding. I'm fetching the data from an API, so it's not just about displaying the data, but inserting it into the database. Could you give me an example of how you'd use a SELECT to achieve this via the change you described to the database structure?